# SQL - Creating Item sets based on Interval data

Tags: sql-server, intervals

I have read a valuable article that explains how to count the number of rows present for each discrete time at this link:
[Intervals and Counts - part1](http://www.itprotoday.com/software-development/intervals-and-counts-part-1)

The Idea is to first for each event create the sequence that represents its start and end times, Then pack those intervals and meanwhile count the number of rows present for each App.

The problem that I have is a little different. I have the same data did the same process and reached a table like this:

```
StartTime       EndTime        App
1               5              A
8               9              A
3               9              B
1               9              C
```

The output of my desire is item sets of co-occurring apps. Laying these intervals on a time diagram can help you understand what I want.

This is the output I'm looking for:

```
StartTime       EndTime        AppsOpen       TimeSpan
1               3              A,C            2
3               5              A,B,C          2
5               8              B,C            3
8               9              A,B,C          1
```

NOTE: The column `TimeSpan` is just the subtraction of `EndTime` and `StartTime`.

p.s: I am using SQLServer 2014.

Answer (score 0):

After Some thinking I decided to find out how I could extract the Final Intervals (i.e: [1:3] , [3:5] , [5:8] , [8:9]).

After that I could only select the rows that either contain the intervals or are contained by them.

The final query looks like this:

note: for brevity, I mapped the column and Table names like this:

> "Ts" means "StartTime",
>
> "Te" means "EndTime",
>
> "E" is the main Table as described above.

```
with p as (select distinct ts from E union select distinct te from E)
,    q as (select ts, lead(ts) over (order by ts) as te from p)
,    X as (select q.Ts, q.Te, app from E inner join q on 
            (E.Ts >= q.Ts and E.Ts < q.Te) -- started in the interval
            or
            (E.Ts <= q.Ts and E.Te > q.Ts)-- started before the interval but present during interval
            )

select Ts,Te, STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(App AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                        FROM X y WHERE (y.Ts = x.Ts and y.Te = x.Te) 
                        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
                        ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,2,'') from X x group by Ts,Te
```

Still, Any new Ideas or better ways are welcomed.